# Abelian Group (Alternative Proof)

Tags: abstract-algebra, group-theory, self-learning, abelian-groups, alternative-proof

**Is there an alternative method to prove**

> $(ab)^{2}=a^{2}b^{2}$ for all elements $a,b \in G \implies$ $(ab)^{-1}=a^{-1}b^{-1}$ for all elements $a,b \in G$.

**then the one I give below?**

Let $G$ be a group and suppose $(ab)^{2}=a^{2}b^{2}$ for all elements $a,b \in G$.

Since $G$ is a group, both $a$ and $b$ have inverses, denoted by $a^{-1}$ and $b^{-1}$, respectively. Multiplication in $G$ is well defined, which mean we can multiply both sides of the equation 
\begin{align*}
a^{-1}((ab)(ab))&=a^{-1}(a^{2}b^{2}) \\
(a^{-1}(ab))(ab)&=(a^{-1}a^{2})b^{2} \\
((a^{-1}a)b)(ab) &=((a^{-1}a)a)b^{2} \\
(eb)(ab)&=(ea)b^{2} \\
b(ab)&=ab^{2}
\end{align*}
Furthermore, we may multiply on the right:
\begin{align*}
(b(ab))b^{-1}&=(ab^{2})b^{-1} \\
ba(bb^{-1})&=ab(bb^{-1}) \\
bae &=abe \\
ba&=ab
\end{align*}
As $G$ is a group, we have, by proposition $3.1.3$ (*Abstract Algebra * by Beachy & Blair, 91), $(ab)^{-1}=b^{-1}a^{-1}$. So, taking the inverse on both sides we arrive have
\begin{equation}
a^{-1}b^{-1}=b^{-1}a^{-1}, \quad \forall a,b \in G
\end{equation}
which proves $(ab)^{-1}=a^{-1}b^{-1}$.